# What's a better way to perform this jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm querying an api and getting a group of people with a photo, name, email and phone number. I'm trying to take that data and insert it into my view with jquery ajax and display it in a bootstrap layout.

When I would do this with commented section it would take the person display all of their data and the remaining ones data. Then it would go to the second index and do the following. So if I had 4 people I would have 4 divs with 4 people, 3 people, 2 people, etc.

I fixed it by having a singular line of js that put it all in one div but it feels icky for some reason like it shouldn't be this way. Is there a better way to do it? Am I putting too much html in my js? How can I clean this up?

```
//This works to give me a div of each person with the h4 and p tags as needed in my layout
$.each(data, function(item) {
    $( '.people').append('<div class="col-md-6 person">
<img class="img img-responsive" src="' + data[item].photo_url + '"><h4>'
 + data[item].full_name + '</h4><p>' + data[item].offices[0].email
 + '</p><p>' + data[item].offices[0].phone + '</p>');

//This just creates a blank div for each person than
iterates through the index for each person
    /*$( '.people').append('<div class="col-md-6 person">');
        $( '.person' ).append('<img class="img img-responsive" src="' + 
data[item].photo_url + '">')
        .append('<h4>' + data[item].full_name + '</h4>')
        .append('<p>' + data[item].offices[0].email + '</p>')
        .append('<p>' + data[item].offices[0].phone + '</p>');*/
});
```

My end goal is to have a div for each person with their image, name, email and phone number in their own elements.

How can I remove as much html from my js? Or is this it?

Thank you

Comment: What's the desidered output?

Comment: Fixed the code block to show what I was trying to do. Didn't catch that it was not formatted properly in the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: @ahackney Would you mind to reformat your source code, so the horizontal scrollbar will disappeare?

Comment: The only suggestion i'd make is to maybe create the string as a variable, format it like you would if it were HTML (with correct indentations) and then append the final string to $('.people'). I'd personally find that easier to read but others may feel differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
var data = [{
  "full_name": "Lillian Gilbert",
  "email": "lgilbert0@geocities.com",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/ff4444/ffffff",
  "phone": "86-(925)179-9301"
}, {
  "full_name": "Eric Dixon",
  "email": "edixon1@symantec.com",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/dddddd/000000",
  "phone": "66-(115)374-7439"
}, {
  "full_name": "Jessica Rodriguez",
  "email": "jrodriguez2@wired.com",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/ff4444/ffffff",
  "phone": "7-(536)585-2870"
}, {
  "full_name": "Juan Wilson",
  "email": "jwilson3@latimes.com",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/cc0000/ffffff",
  "phone": "7-(257)204-7934"
}, {
  "full_name": "Samuel Hill",
  "email": "shill4@altervista.org",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/cc0000/ffffff",
  "phone": "63-(328)705-8980"
}, {
  "full_name": "Louis Ruiz",
  "email": "lruiz5@pagesperso-orange.fr",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/dddddd/000000",
  "phone": "46-(888)764-8155"
}, {
  "full_name": "Clarence Larson",
  "email": "clarson6@facebook.com",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/ff4444/ffffff",
  "phone": "58-(422)543-6609"
}, {
  "full_name": "Carlos Mendoza",
  "email": "cmendoza7@opensource.org",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/5fa2dd/ffffff",
  "phone": "7-(624)453-7787"
}, {
  "full_name": "Irene Dean",
  "email": "idean8@msn.com",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/cc0000/ffffff",
  "phone": "598-(462)226-1135"
}, {
  "full_name": "Frank Ramos",
  "email": "framos9@delicious.com",
  "photo": "http://dummyimage.com/50x50.jpg/cc0000/ffffff",
  "phone": "64-(204)933-8956"
}];

var people = $('.people');
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  var person = {
    photo: '<img class="img img-responsive" src="' + item.photo + '">',
    name: '<h4>' + item.full_name + '</h4>',
    email: '<p>' + item.email + '</p>',
    phone: item.phone
  };
  people.append('<div class="col-md-6 person">' + person.photo + person.name + person.email + person.phone + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="people"></div>
```

Comment: This is what they're already doing, See the updated question (except you've done your example in a table, which isn't what they want)

Comment: @DibsyJr How about this one?

Comment: The object seems unnecessary, I propose using a string and building up the HTML before appending it, if the strings are formatted to look similar to how they would in HTML then I find it improves readability

Comment: Is there way to remove some of the html from the JS? Or is that just how it has to be?

Comment: @ahackney Not that I know of. At least, not if you want to be able to style it, because if you strip out some of the HTML then it'll lose some of it's structure, so you'd just be appending plain text to an already existing element. The only other way I know of would be to have the HTML in the HTML file, but then you'd only be able to have a few entries without the HTML becoming really bulky.

Comment: @DibsyJr Ok, thank you!